# Teechart + Auto Color turns gray for most of the bar

Tags: activex, teechart

I am adding a series spGraph.Series(count).Add(fTmpValue,pLabelText->GetAt(nActualPoint),536870912);Please let me know how to solve this.

[image]

Comment: Can you attached for us your complete code because we can try to solve your problem? You can add your code here or send an e-mail with project to sales department at "sales at steema dot com" addressed To Sandra

Comment: The Code is Simple. I have a For Loop in which I have 50 points and adding that to a single Series spGraph.Series(count).Add(fTmpValue,pLabelText->GetAt(nActualPoint),536870912);

Comment: Hello Akshay Bhalla, I can not reproduce your problem, I have made a simple code following your explanation and your problem doesn't appears for me, please, try to arrange a simple project and send it to "sales at steema dot com" addressed to Sandra, because we can try to suggest a solution for you.